# Why does Sum[Length[Divisors[a]], {a, 1 ,x}] return x?

Tags: functions, summation

I am summing the number of divisors and I am getting the strange answer below even where there is no input to this function.

```
Sum[Length[Divisors[a]], {a, 1, x}]
(*  x  *)
```

Comment: Because your code doesn't "know" what $x$ is.

Comment: Length[Divisors[a]] counts the divisors, so everything else is redundant. Are you looking for the sum of divisors? If yes, it is Total[Divisors[a]]

Comment: @Titus:  I believe the OP wants to sum the divisors of *all* integers up to $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note what the summand equals:

```
Length[Divisors[a]]
(*  1  *)
```

Why `1`?  Note what `Divisors[a]` returns:

```
Divisors[a]
(*  Divisors[a]  *)
```

Since `Divisors[a]` has only one argument, its `Length[]` is `1`.

Now  `Sum[1, {a, 1, x}]` is in fact equal to `x`.  Understanding what is actually evaluated shows that the answer is not strange; rather, it's correct.

(`Trace[Sum[Length[Divisors[a]], {a, 1, x}]]` is also a way to inspect what is actually evaluated.)

P.S. Perhaps `Sum[DivisorSigma[0, a], {a, 1, x}]` is what the OP actually wants.

Comment: The length of an unspecified variable being one makes sense and explains this problem.  I was using this function in an unevaluated form then substituting its argument later only to find it returning an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
fn[x_?IntegerQ] := Sum[Length[Divisors[a]], {a, 1, x}]

fn[3]
(*5*)

fn[10]
(*27*)

fn[3.5]
(*fn[3.5]*)

fn[x]
(*fn[x]*)
```

I don't know if this is what you want, but it gives the total number of divisors for numbers from 1 to Integer x.

Comment: This is what used however if i write fn[x] it returns x when it should be unevaluated

Comment: @LorenzHMenke:  Of course... that's because `fn[x]` is not defined.

Comment: @LorenzHMenke: See my update.